# DOM Elements created with jQuery AJAX call not freed from memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I asked this yesterday but have added more information and restructured the question.

I have built a web app for a digital signage system that will be constantly running.

There is a `jQuery` `AJAX` call that retrieves html from the server and replaces the content of a `div` with the response so that there is no visible  ugly page refresh.

The problem is that the browser is running out of memory and crashing after several hours of operation. Looking at the timeline in Chrome, it seems that although the `HTML` elements are replaced, they are somehow kept in the DOM.

The following `jQuery` code produces the following timeline:

```
function loadDiary()
    {
    if ((diaryBusy == false) && (navigatorOnline))
        {
        diaryBusy = true;

        $.ajax  (
                    {
                    url     : '/get/data/from/server',

                    cache   : false,

                    success : function(response)
                                {
                                $('#diary').empty();                                                                                                                   
                                $('#diary').html(response);

                                diaryBusy = false;
                                loadDiaryTimer();
                                },

                    error   : function()
                                {
                                diaryBusy = false;
                                loadDiaryTimer();
                                }
                    }
                );
        }
    }
```

[image: Chrome timeline for jQuery Ajax call]

The following `javascript` produces the following timeline:

```
function loadDiary()
    {
    if ((diaryBusy == false) && (navigatorOnline))
        {
        diaryBusy = true;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById('diary').innerHTML = '';
                    document.getElementById('diary').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    diaryBusy = false;
                    loadDiaryTimer();
                    }
            }

        xmlhttp.open('GET','/get/data/from/server',true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

[image: Chrome timeline not using jQuer Ajax call]

You can see that with the `jQuery` the number of nodes growing to 358278 in the short test when only 1835 are required.

This is forcing garbage collection sooner yet the memory usage increases over time.

In the second example, the maximum number of nodes is 1835 and garbage collection was never needed.

The second piece of code would be fine, but I need to attach a `jQuery` plugin to some of the dynamic content so a non `jQuery` solution isn't an option.

Any suggestions why this may be happening and how to stop the number of elements growing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you limiting the amount of data being received and i see you empty the `diary` element, are you pushing old + new data back into this element? For exmaple first call: `test1` call moments later `test1 test2 test3` ?

Comment: The size of data received will vary slightly but all previous data (html elements) should be replaced and not appended. Its basically a table 15 x 5 and the content is updated.